# tf.strings.format automatically wraps a scalar tensor as a list

Tags: python, tensorflow

`tf.strings.format` function automatically wraps a solitary tensor as a list.

For example what if I want to do something like this:

```py
x = tf.convert_to_tensor('x')
[tf.strings.format("/path/to/directory/{}_{}.png", (x, y)) for y in range(2)]
```

The output will be:

```py
[<tf.Tensor: id=712, shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'/path/to/directory/[x]_0.png'>,
 <tf.Tensor: id=714, shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'/path/to/directory/[x]_1.png'>]
```

Whereas a desired output is:

```py
[<tf.Tensor: id=712, shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'/path/to/directory/x_0.png'>,
 <tf.Tensor: id=714, shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'/path/to/directory/x_1.png'>]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

You can concatenate strings normally with `+` operator:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    x = tf.convert_to_tensor('x')
    path = tf.constant("/path/to/directory/")
    sep = tf.constant("_")
    ext = tf.constant(".png")
    res = [path + x + sep + tf.constant(str(y)) + ext for y in range(2)]
    print(sess.run(res))
    # [b'/path/to/directory/x_0.png', b'/path/to/directory/x_1.png']
```

Or, if you don't mind recreating constant tensors (which you probably don't in eager mode), just:

```
res = ["/path/to/directory/" + x + "_" + str(y) + ".png" for y in range(2)]
```

---

You can get the result you want with [`tf.strings.join`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strings/join):

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    a = tf.convert_to_tensor('a')
    b = tf.convert_to_tensor('b')
    c = tf.convert_to_tensor('c')
    print(sess.run(tf.strings.join([a, b, c], '/')))
    # b'a/b/c'
```